# How choose specific ButtonColumn in C#

Tags: c#, button, datagridview

I have DataGridView with 2 colors: RED and ForestGreen , and also CELL 'Check-Out'( i make it ButtonColumn.

[image]

when I click to any CELL Ceck-OUT button , i have :

[image]

this is the code:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (MessageBox.Show("Check-out?",
                       "Message de confirmation",
                       MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {  // non

            MessageBox.Show("Opération éffectuée");
        }
```

BUT I want jsut WHEN I click to CELL button which have a color RED !

I try this code:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
       foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
       {
           if (dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
           {

               if (MessageBox.Show("Check-out?",
                              "Message de confirmation",
                              MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
               {  // non

                   MessageBox.Show("Opération éffectuée");
               }
           }
       }
```

I don't have anything!

How can I fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you mean show message popup only red rows alright ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // must selected row first
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
                return;

            // not support multiple rows select
            if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Check-out?",
                                  "Message de confirmation",
                                  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {  // non

                    MessageBox.Show("Opération éffectuée");
                }
            }        
        }
```